# How to have partially-colored row in a table?

Tags: tables, color

Is it possible to color a row partially? In the example below, I don't want the very first cell to be colored, just from column 2 onwards. How can I achieve this? Also, the top rule is not starting properly (its leftmost point seems off towards the right)... is it possible to have it intersect the vertical edge perfectly?
Thanks, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{RowColor1}{rgb}{0.8078,0.8627,0.8824}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{@{}?l?cc|cc|cc?@{}}
\cmidrule[1.0pt]{2-7}
\rowcolor{RowColor1}\multicolumn{1}{l?}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Header 1}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Header 2}& \multicolumn{2}{c?}{Header 3} \\
\cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-7}
Row 2& Value 1& Value 2& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Some text}& Value 3& Value 4 \\
Row 3& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{--}& Value 5 & Value 6& \multicolumn{2}{c?}{--} \\
\cmidrule[1.0pt]{1-7}
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

**edit:**
better mimic (with some dirty trick) of desired table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{RowColor1}{rgb}{0.8078,0.8627,0.8824}
\newcommand\mccolor[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{RowColor1}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]                %  <---
    \small                           %  <--- it is switch, not environment
\begin{tabular}{@{}?l?cc|cc|cc?@{}}
    \cmidrule[1.0pt](l{-2pt}){2-7}   %  <---
\multicolumn{1}{c?}{}                %  <---
        & \mccolor{Header 1}& \mccolor{Header 2}& \multicolumn{2}{c?}{\cellcolor{RowColor1}{Header 3}} \\
    \midrule[1.0pt]
Row 2   & Value 1                   & Value 2   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Some text}    & Value 3& Value 4 \\
Row 3   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{--}   & Value 5   & Value 6                           & \multicolumn{2}{c?}{--} \\
    \midrule[1.0pt]
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

to my taste this table is not beautiful. i more like if all tabular lines have the same width.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks for your help, Zarko!. Any idea on how to fix the top rule left edge? :) P.S. I know the layout is terrible, but unfortunately that's beyond my control (it's for a multi-author paper!)

Comment: this can be simply done if you all tabular lines has the same width. latex doesn't support "ugly" table design well :-)

Comment: So I should force the widths to be the same? how? I guess in this example is LaTeX itself deciding the widths, right?

Comment: @dontpanic, see edited answer.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean! Interesting! (Wonder what exactly makes LaTeX miscalculate the rules when widths are nor equal!) Anyway, thank you so much again for your help, Zarko!

Comment: @dontpanic, `latex` calculate tabular lines correctly, however, you should not require something what `tabular` support :-).  now i correct some small glitch in provide code, which  now enable compile it as it is.